# Update a single view with uicollection view Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collections, view

I have a view with a grid movies. There's three properties: title Label, image view for poster movie and a image to show if a movie is or not favored.

When click on a cell, go on to a detail view with show others infos about the movie and there's a button action to favor a movie. I wish update the button icon in grid collection view. So I create a delegate to listen when this event occurs and then reload the collection view.
Screenshots:

[grid movies screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHadL.jpg)

[detail movie screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dgft.jpg)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.titleLabel.text = popularMovies[indexPath.row].title
    
    getImageMovies(imageURLString: popularMovies[indexPath.row].poster, imageView: cell.movieImage)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailMovieViewController = DetailMovieViewController()
    
    detailMovieViewController.titleMovieLabel.text = popularMovies[indexPath.row].title
    detailMovieViewController.releaseDateMovieLabel.text = popularMovies[indexPath.row].date
    detailMovieViewController.overviewMovieLabel.text = popularMovies[indexPath.row].overview
    
    getImageMovies(imageURLString: popularMovies[indexPath.row].poster, imageView: detailMovieViewController.movieImage)
    
    getGenresMovies(genresMoviesID: popularMovies[indexPath.row].genre, genreMovieLabel: detailMovieViewController.genreMovieLabel)
    
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    detailMovieViewController.delegate = self
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailMovieViewController, animated: true)
    
    
}


protocol favoriteMovieDelegate: class {
func updateFavoriteImage ()
}

@objc func markFavoriteButtom (buttom: UIButton){
    
    if buttom.isSelected == false {
        buttom.isSelected = true
    }else {
        buttom.isSelected = false
    }
    
    delegate?.updateFavoriteImage()
    
}


func updateFavoriteImage() {
    
    if let indexPath = selectedIndexPath {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.favoriteIconImage.image = UIImage(named: "favorite_full_icon")
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}


struct Films: Codable {
   let id: Int
   let title: String
   let poster: String
   let genre: [Int]
   let date: String
   let overview: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case title
    case poster = "poster_path"
    case genre = "genre_ids"
    case date = "release_date"
    case overview
}
```

}

Comment: you are not setting `favoriteIconImage` in cellForItem ?

Comment: post your `cellForItem` method

Comment: instead of updating directly your cell.favoriteIconImage.image you will have to update your object directly and then reload CollectionView. and As @jawadAli, mention you need to set fav image on cellForItem

Comment: @jawadAli No, by default the cells start with an image with the favorite gray icon. The title and image of the film comes from API The Movie DB

Comment: @jawadAli. I put the method cellForItem

Comment: @SergioTrejo This favoriteicon image belongs to the cell class. My object is a struct for retrieves json data from API

Comment: you are not storing isFav anywhere ?

Comment: just stop `collectionView.reloadData()` after setting fav ;)

Comment: @jawadAli You're right. I will create a class model to manage isFav. It doesn't really make sense what I'm doing. collectionView.cellForItem (at: indexPath) returns a cell reference or a copy?

Comment: it will return cell reference

Comment: you need to post that to server once user make it fav ... and fetch isFav from server if you want to persist data

Comment: @jawadAli The server don't provide fav property.

Comment: then you need to store it locally against film id ... in user deefault

Comment: @jawadAli I do this. It works, thanks for help.

Comment: Can i post it as answer ?

Comment: @jawadAli Yes, at will!

Comment: updated my answer ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating directly your `cell.favoriteIconImage.image` you will have to update your object directly and then reload `CollectionView`. you need to set fav image on `cellForItem` Also you need to post that to server once user make it fav ... and fetch `isFav` from server if you want to persist data. And if your server did not support `isFav` then you need to store it locally against `film Id` ... in `user default`